# how can I get lesk similarity score for all the senses of given words using ws4j library?

Tags: nlp, wordnet, word-sense-disambiguation, wsd, ws4j

I am trying to get LESK similarity score between all the senses of two words using [ws4j](https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/) as provided on its online [ws4j demo](http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com/) in the format **word#pos#sense** number for all the senses of both the words but I am not able to find how to get result in same format using ws4j library ?? As there is no proper documentation available for ws4j and the demo/sample code for this library only given maximum value only which also don't tell about which senses has got that score..

can anybody help ?